# How to connect to SVN using PuTTY and private key in PhpStorm

Tags: windows, svn, ssh, phpstorm, putty

friends.
I can't connect to svn using PuTTY.

1. I have private key and working pageagent by PuTTY;
2. Windows 7 and PhpStorm 9;
3. I have remote url as svn+ssh://host.to.svn.repository;

**Problem**: I don't have a password, i have only private key.
[image: Failed to connect]

I specified this data in dialog:

[image]

But update it uses old data:

[image]

I tried "Clear Auth Cache", but it's not helped me.

I want ro work with SVN via PhpStorm.
P.S. TortoiseSVN work fine.

**RESOLVE**:

1. Setting -> Version Control -> Subversion -> SSH Settings;
2. Select "Subversion config" and specify a path to the plink and path to the private key, using parameter "-i";

Example:
[image]

1 - Path to plink;
2 - Parameter "-i";
3 - Path to your private key;

**P.S.** Make sure to check the "Enable interactive mode" is **removed** in General tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up all options for svn+ssh in the PhpStorm settings:

1. Go to File -> Settings
2. Go to Version Control -> Subversion
3. Click the SSH Settings tab
4. Here you can specify the path to you SSH client and set up the credentials for the connection.

[image: Screenshot of settings window]

Comment: Should I fill SSH exetubale? svn+ssh://host.to.repo ?

Comment: I don't have a password, i have only private key.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/1AIPX.jpg

Comment: SSH executable should point to your SSH client, putty for example.

As for not using a password: simply select the private key option in that window and input the path to your private key file.

More information: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/subversion.html#d734354e298

Comment: I specified this data in dialog: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbu5w.png
But update it uses old data: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sguhE.jpg
I tried "Clear Auth Cache", but it's not helped me.